# Using MS Load Test, is it possible to control test flow by number of tests started per minute

Tags: performance, performance-testing, load-testing, msloadtest

My application uses MS Load test. We are currently running tests configured to Add X threads per minute, up to a given maximum, and once each thread finishes its test, it immediately starts another test.

However, in our production system, we use a queuing system to allow Y users per minute to enter the site. But when each user finishes their purchase, they just log off.

This difference in behavior leads to wildly different results in metrics like orders per minute, even if X = Y, and the maximum number of users on the site is the same.

Is there any way to configure MS Load Test to behave more like the second case? Launch Y number of tests per minute, but when that test finishes, don't run another one?

Comment: See my explanation of "User pace" test mix in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52210691/546871 .  Your question might be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Hrm, since I just found out that MS Load Test is being deprecated, I guess I will just switch to JMeter or something anyway :)