# Configure # of Request per Second for Load Testing

Tags: visual-studio, performance, azure, testing, performance-testing

In Visual Studio 2017 Load Tests, is there any way to configure the # of request per second? I would like to limit the test to 40 requests per second.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The option that is closest to what you ask is to set a test mix of "user pace" in the scenario. See the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52210691/546871) for more info on the various test mixes.

Another possibility is to choose a slower network configuration in the scenario. You can use an existing mix. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/specify-virtual-network-types-in-a-load-test-scenario?view=vs-2019) for more about network mixes. There is some more information in pages 159 and 160 of the  of the [Visual Studio Performance Testing Quick Reference Guide" (Version 3.6)](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=vsptqrg). You can also create your own by copying an modifying an existing mix in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Templates\LoadTest\Networks` (modified as needed for your Visual Studio version and install directory). I have not found any documentation on the contents of these network files.